# loading first time twice in angular ssr 9

Tags: angular, angular-routing, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I having project with angular ssr 9.
this work with `ng serve` correctly.
but when build with `npm run build:ssr` and run server.js
loading first time twice in `http://localhost:4000` and there is fickering in loading first.
I tried very hard to find a cause but couldn't.

[image]

**source:** [source my project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ETi4ycSh3-hAG5KpGVDeTslskMoOwHTB/view?usp=sharing)
If anyone can find a cause, thank you.

Comment: How do you add your script/links? Probably what's happening is that SSR adds them once, then when client side app takes over, it adds the links again

Comment: https://github.com/angular/universal/issues/1546